# Creating a uiview animation "drone" or "slave"?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have created a uiview subclass, and instantiated it (lets call it the master view). This uiview subclass contains it's own gesture recognizers and touch event overrides as well as the animations corresponding to these touch events (e.g. rotation and flipping).

I would like to create another instantiation of this subclass (or similar subclass) that we will call the slave view. The slave view should be identical to the master in appearance, but will not respond to touch events itself. Instead, the slave should in essence be a remote controlled drone that animates in lock step with master view.

I was trying to get my brain around how to do this... it seems that maybe I could create a slave subclass such that the master can call animation delegate methods for the slave view. So every animation call in the Master would also call a method in the slave with the same transform.

The parent view will have multiple master-slave pairs, each master-slave pair animated independently. I really prefer not to move the gesture-recognizers and animation to the parent level.

Any thoughts on a code pattern for this master-slave pair? My understanding of calling delegates might be challenged, but I get the feeling that delegate methods will not work here when I go to more than one master/slave pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which object creates the slave? The parent view or the master? If you have master create its own slave, then it can set itself as the delegate of the slave. There shouldn't be any trouble with having multiple pairs, because each master will be the delegate of a specific instance of the slave class.

Comment: Originally thought the parent view would create and position the slave. But I guess I can have the master create the slave view, and then return the id value of the slave view to the parent for positioning? This might have been the missing piece in my thought process.

Comment: Technically this is not a protocol situation, right? The master will simply instantiate the slave and return the slave object id to the parent for positioning. Then the master will simply call a slave method every time it needs to animate, right? I think my confusion came from the notion that a master could create a slave view without it having to be a subview of the master. But seems obvious now. Duh.

Comment: @DawglessBoyd, yeah, that's true. If the master is just setting things in the slave, and you don't need to send any info back to the master from the slave, then a delegate isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks to both of you (rdelmar & inafziger). I will pursue the simple notion of having the master create the slave. You guys put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

After your comment, I realized that I mis-understood your question.  Having the slave be the delegate of appropriate master is the way to go.  Once it is setup that way, then the master can call the delegate methods when appropriate (assuming that a delegate is set, of course).

Comment: I thought about using notifications... seemed a little untidy because I really don't need a broadcast model, just synchronization of a master-slave pair. The untidy part (just a feeling) is that each master must create it's own unique notification queues.... I suppose I could base these off the master's object id though. I guess userInfo could be used to send the transform.  I will think this through a bit further.

Comment: Well, if it was just a master-slave pair, then I would say delegate. But, as you said, it is master-multiple-slaves, so the broadcast model is appropriate here.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I will have multiple master/slave PAIRS... that is master/slave-A, master/slave-B, master/slave-C. So instantiation slaveA will only track/synchronize to the animation of masterA, and so forth. I may be missing something here, but I could not get my head around how delegation can work on the instantiation level... that is how can slaveA only delegate to MasterA, and slaveB only delegate to MasterB, etc.

Comment: Oh, in that case, then each slave should be the delegate of the appropriate master.  Each one is a one-to-one relationship.